# Найти подстроку в строке

Tags: python

Пытаюсь понять, как решить достаточно тривиальную задачку в Python. Дана строка вида `Текст без кавычек «Текст в кавычках»`. Мне нужно извлечь из неё только текст `Текст в кавычках`, отбросив кавычки.

Вероятно нужно применить регулярные выражения, но как именно построить конструкцию - понять нем могу.

Comment: Рекомендую обратиться к чему-нибудь вроде "Вводный курс по регулярным выражениям" (допустим, что первое попалось, https://proglib.io/p/regexp-digest/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно так `«(.*)»`. А потом модуль `re` в помощь.

Проверка этой регулярки https://regex101.com/r/F8Sur4/1

Скобки - спецсимволы, которые определяют начало и конец захватываемой группы. Точка - значит любой символ. Звездочка - любое количество символов от нуля до бесконечности, которые перед ней.

В итоге .* - значит совершенно произвольная последовательность символов. А если поместить ее в скобки, то она будет сохранена отдельно, например, функцией `re.match`.

Ну а кавычки - это кавычки.

Comment: Работает, спасибо!
Если ещё немного расскажите, логику работу, буду совсем благодарен :)
а-то пояснения для каждого отдельного символа в [статье](https://tproger.ru/translations/regular-expression-python/) мне не помогают.

Comment: Добавил пояснения в ответ. Рекомендую открыть для себя "Хабр". https://habr.com/en/post/349860/, https://habr.com/en/company/badoo/blog/343310/, https://habr.com/en/post/115825/. Для программиста критически важно уметь находить информацию, советую подумать над этим.

Answer (score 1):

Можете, если захочется БДСМ-а, сами написать механизм регулярных выражений. Иногда бывает весело)

```
s = 'Текст без кавычек «Текст в кавычках». Мама мыла раму «Ещё немного текста в кавычках». Чё-то ещё и «Сколько угодно текста в кавычках»'

result = []
status = 0
temp_string = ''

for letter in s:

    if status == 0 and letter not in '«»':
        continue
    else:
        if letter == '«':
            status = 1
            continue
        elif letter == '»':
            status = 0
            result.append(temp_string)
            temp_string = ''
            continue
        else:
            temp_string += letter

print(result)
```